# mysql query how to fill in blank rows using the value of its top row with content?

Tags: php, mysql

I need a mysql query to do this 
But I can't think of something to make this happened

We have an excel file and that contains more than 5,000 rows 
some are blank and others have value what I manually do is 
to copy top value to its below blank fields and so on 
so I think a way that I can import the excel into myslq database
and make some query to save effort and time in terms of doing this..

and this is my table looks like:

only column Date-paid has value for the entire rows but some has value and other don't have see this example but the original file is more than 5,000 rows

```
|Name |  age  | Salary| Date_paid |
-----------------------------------
bbjake| 16    | 200   | 03/25/2015 |
----------------------------------|
      |       |       | 04/25/2015 |
----------------------------------
      |       |       | 05/25/2015 |
-----------------------------------
kentot| 20    | 300   | 03/25/2015 |
-----------------------------------
      |       |       | 04/25/2015 |
----------------------------------|
      |       |       | 05/25/2015 |
-----------------------------------
```

and after running the query this is my desired result

```
|Name |  age  | Salary| Date_paid |
----------------------------------|
bbjake| 16    | 200   | 03/25/2015 |
-----------------------------------
bbjake| 16    | 200   | 04/25/2015 |
-----------------------------------
bbjake| 16    | 200   | 05/25/2015 |
-----------------------------------
kentot| 20    | 300   | 03/25/2015 |
-----------------------------------
kentot| 20    | 300   | 04/25/2015 |
-----------------------------------
kentot| 20    | 300   | 05/25/2015 |
-----------------------------------
```

So blank fields will be filled in with the value on the raw with content and 
drag down until with another raw with value in short will fill in blank rows with 
the content of top row

table is manually imported into the database and  let just say columns are only three Name(varchar) Age(int) Salary (int) Date Paid (Date) Table name = "Emplyoee" Database name = "Company"

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: Sure, you just would have to modify your loop slightly which creates that table structure. But we cannot help you with that if you don't post your code.

Comment: Dates in SQL adhere to a specific format and data type. Fix that, then get back to us.

Comment: I can only provide the details of my databased and column name but I am still seeking for a query to update my table and fill in blank contents with the row with value

Comment: done editing with Date data is manually imported into database but the data structure is in above example so I need to fill in those blanks with the top value and that waste my time so I think php with mysql query can solve this

Answer (score 0):

your question is strange...why would somebody wanna do this?

Anyway, to do this, it's interesting, how this table is created / generated. Your question is very weird...i think you want to know, how to fill this table AFTER the server built it and created the HTML table (because of your post title here). On the other side, this "php" tag does not make any sense in this scope....

JavaScript solution:

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var innerHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++){
  if (trs[i].className !== "heading") {
    innerHTML = (trs[i].innerHTML.children[0] == "") ? innerHTML : trs[i].innerHTML;
    trs[i].innerHTML = innerHTML;
  }
}
```

note that you have to set the classname of the description rows to "heading" in this example, that this will not be interpreted from the script. If your server alone shall do this, just follow the same logic like in my JavaScript. Always check, if next element would be empty - if yes: fill in the same string like before; if not: take the new string and fill it into all next empty cells, etc....

Comment: I want to do this because I manually do it in a 5,000 plus number of lines  so I think importing it into the database and run a mysql query can make this happened in just less than a minute

Comment: but why to fill the empty rows with the same contents?

Comment: edited in my table some columns have value for the entire rows and what I want to achieve is to make a query just to fill in the blank fields with values on top

Comment: you have an empty mysql table and want to refill this table? i thought, you are talking about an HTML table

Comment: I have a mysql table and it is not empty I imported a CSV file on it and case is some rows are blank and instruction is to fill it in with value on its top so copy and drag down and if it can see another value copy and drag down and so on

Comment: do you use fgetcsv() to read the file? http://php.net/manual/de/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: I just manually imported the file but hmtl table will do if that would be easy and without updating the table content in the database disply html table and fill in can do

Comment: I am not reading the CSV I just imported its content manually in the database by clicking import button